# Noip dynamic client installing Problem Configuration file can NOT be created

Tags: linux, debian-based, noip

I follow the installation process from http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/installing-the-linux-dynamic-update-client-on-ubuntu/

While installing i get a kind of error.

**Configuration file can NOT be created.**

Auto configuration for Linux client of no-ip.com.

Please enter the login/email string for no-ip.com  ******Email*****.com

Please enter the password for user '******Email*****.com'  *********

No hosts are available for this user.

Go to www.no-ip.com and create some!

```
mv /tmp/no-ip2.conf /usr/local/etc/no-ip2.conf
mv: cannot stat '/tmp/no-ip2.conf': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:32: install] Error 1
```

A bug while copy the `/tmp/no-ip2.conf`

A bug while copy the `/tmp/no-ip2.conf` using script of make install.

This `no-ip2.conf` file is missing or it make a random name of a file which is create in each command of `make install`. This is the name of created file `NO-IPTIziyV` in `/tmp/` directory.

**But my credentials are correct.
The script create a wrong name file which make the error while moving the file in `/usr/local/etc/` directory.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. I assume it was a bug at the noip side. As a workaround I regsitered my addresses again and reinstalled the client.

1)I installed the windows client on a windows machine and observed the
same strange behavior. (Windows client didn't find my hostnames either, although they were indeed registered.)

2) Removed my host names at noip.com and registered them again.

3) Then checked that the windows client has found my host names.

4) I put the following lines into the install script

(source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=160038)
/usr/local/bin/noip-2.1.9-1# nano Makefile

Check the link because this text editor doesn't let me paste it for some reason. Please consider that the script Makefile is indented with tabs and not with spaces.

5) I uninstalled the client

/usr/local/bin/noip-2.1.9-1# make uninstall

6) Than ran the install again. Now everything seems to be fine.